# ttsbegin, ttscommit and "~" operator 

Tags: axapta, x++

I'm learning X++ and i have 2 question:

I don't understand what is the utility of `ttsbegin and ttscommit` ! 
where i must use it and what's the utility?

[X++ Standards: ttsBegin and ttsCommit AX 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa609617.aspx)

What is the utility of this operator "~"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa622564.aspx):

> `ttsBegin`: marks the beginning of a transaction. This ensures data integrity, and guarantees that all updates performed until the transaction ends (by `ttsCommit` or `ttsAbort`) are consistent (all or none).
>
> `ttsCommit`: marks the successful end of a transaction. This ends and commits a transaction. MorphX guarantees that a committed transaction will be performed according to intentions.

Note  that

> It is usually better to use exception handling instead of `ttsAbort`. The throw statement automatically aborts the current transaction.

This means that you would begin a transaction with `ttsBegin` and end it with `ttsCommit` (if successful) or throw an exception (if the transaction is unsuccessful).  It is unclear from the documentation, but transactions mean manipulation of application tables.

You would use them when you want to ensure that your read or update operations on application tables are not made inconsistent by other table operations that happen simultaneously

See examples at the same link.

The [`~` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa870833) is bitwise not, that flips each bit in an integer number.  For example, (assuming 32 bit integer): `~0` is `FFFFFFFF` (each bit is now 1), `~4` is `FFFFFFFB` (hexadecimal representation).

Answer (score 1):

Use ttsbegin when you what to access data in tables, it informs the system that transactions to the DB is going to take place.
 When you update/save the data in a row you have to call ttscommit otherwise the changes will revert to original values, similar to when you use Data-sets in C#/VB you have to tell the data-set to commit all changes to the database.

ttsbegin is like the BEGIN SQL statement and ttscommit is like the COMMIT SQL statement.

You Have to use them together:
ttsbegin;
'add code here to retrieve data and manipulate data'
ttscommit;

You are aloud to nest ttsbegins and ttscommits, but BE CAREFUL of multiple use of the above as not closing one ttsbegin can screw up a lot of things and I have found that calling ttsbegin and ttscommit once is enough.

As for the the '~', I have never used it before in 2years of X++ coding for Axapta(Microsoft Dynamics AX).